# bootstrap-select overrides dropdown styles

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-select

Im using class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" on my dropdown. The live search works and all but
my dropdown does not look like my other dropdowns. I would like bootstrap-select to inherit styles from parents so that the dropdown and searchbox (inside dropdown) would look like all my other textboxes.

Comment: can you show us your code? its will help to resopnd to the question better

Comment: <code><select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select></code>

Comment: class="selectpicker" will create a button which class is "btn dropdown-toggle btn-light",and what you see is the button css,not the select css,so it's hard to change the button css as the common select has.